# Bluetooth Sniffer recommendation

Tags: bluetooth

I'm looking for recommendation on Bluetooth traffic sniffer instrument.
I did my desk research to find-out the instruments available - I came across Nordic, Ubertooth etc..  but these are not meeting my requirements.

I would like to have ready-to-use instrument for bluetooth without dependency of installing drivers or laptop

Supporting Bluetooth BR, EDR, BLE protocols with internet connection facility to download the logs/reports/captures

Thanks in advance
Santhosh

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without dependency of installing drivers or laptop". Are you asking for self-contained hardware dedicated to sniffing and relaying  the captured data via TCP/IP?